# Updating chart.js in AJAX doesn't render the graph properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts

I am trying to plot a line chart using chart.js with AJAX but the chart is not plotted properly when data comes from server. The chart is plotting fine on window onload event but with AJAX it failed to render properly. What could be the issue? Here is my code -

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AJAX JSON Chart</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
var lineChartData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]

}

window.onload = function(){
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    responsive: false
});
}

// ajax part of chart //
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#frm1").submit(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var btnchart = $("#btnchart").attr("name") + "=" + $("#btnchart").val();
        $.ajax({
            //beforeSend: function(){ sendRequest("canvas"); },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "ajax/chart.php",
            data: $(this).serialize() + "&" + btnchart,
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data.labels);
                //alert(data.points);
                renderGraph(data.labels, data.points, ctx);
            },
        });
    return false;
    });
});

var renderGraph = function (labels, points, ctx) {

        var lineChartData = {
                        labels: "[" +  labels + "]",
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "Recent Orders",
                                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                data: "[" +  points + "]", 
                            }
                        ]
                    };


        var myChart = new Chart(ctx)
                                .Line(lineChartData, {
                                        responsive: false,
                                        animation: false
                                        });
                                        myChart.update(lineChartData);

    }

function sendRequest(id)
{
    $("#"+id).html('<div style="width:100px; margin:0 auto;"><img id="loader-img" alt="" src="images/preloader.gif" width="100" height="100" /></div>');
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:30%">
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="960"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<form id="frm1" name="frm1" method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" name="btnchart" id="btnchart" value="Draw Chart" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**chart.php:**

```
<?php
$labels = array('29 April 2015', '30 April 2015', '1 May 2015', '2 May 2015', '3 May 2015', '4 May 2015', '5 May 2015');
$points = array('100', '250', '10', '35', '73', '0', '25');
echo json_encode(array('labels' => $labels, 'points' => $points));
?>
```

On first time page loads, the output is:

[image]

After clicking button "Draw Chart", the output comes through AJAX is:

[image]

But when i hover my mouse over the image, it automatically converts into first image i.e. the first correct graph when window was loaded. Strange!!!

Comment: I'm trying to implement the same kind of functionality but can't find the right algorithm. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I changed the entire code. Now I am not using this library chart.js anymore.

Comment: Use [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/) to achieve the required goal with some cool effects.

Answer (score 0):

so before drawing your chart again, what you can do just destroy the earlier created chart with

```
myChart.destroy();
```

or

```
myChart.clear();
```

and then redraw your chart. Then hopefully it will work correct